# Wheels for CAAD 10 Disc

Tags: wheels, cannondale, disc-brake

I have a CAAD 10 disc frame and want to find the right wheels to match.

I've seen that the Maddux RD 2.0 rims come with many complete bikes for the CAAD 10 but can't find much information on them.

What size should I be looking for to match this frame?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CAAD10 disc frame uses 700c wheels with standard hub spacings (135 mm rear, 100 mm front). The [width of the rim](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#width)  you should choose depends on the size of tire you intend to run (which is limited by your frame). It looks like the bike was originally spec'd for 700x25 tires. Based on other Cannondales, I'd guess this is somewhat tight to begin with, but if you're lucky you might be able to run 700x28's. So, pick the rim width accordingly (likely 13-17 mm).

I'd suggest buying complete wheels (or getting a wheel made by a competent wheelbuilder, who should work with you on selecting appropriate rim+hubs+spokes for your needs). Note that you need disc brake hubs on a CAAD10 disc, and your rotors have to be compatible with the hub (or you have to use an adapter).

Often, you can't get the exact parts spec'd from OEM's (there are lines of parts specifically for OEMs). But its not hard to find equivalents or improvements for around the same price (even if you can get them).

Note that a decent number of wheels (especially cheaper ones) need some adjustment before they're ready for the road (even if they're brand new) -- you'll likely want to use a bike shop for this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. On the rotors and hubs, I thought the hexagon shape hub for the disc was a standard, is is not?

Comment: You can get both  centerlock and 6 bolt wheels.

Comment: So if I wanted to stay with 700x25 tires I could go with a 15mm rim? Would these be right? Had hoped to find something cheaper :) http://www.wiggle.co.uk/fulcrum-racing-sport-disc-brake-alloy-clincher-wheelset/ and http://www.amazon.co.uk/Schwalbe-Lugano-Racing-Puncture-Protection/dp/B00Y32158C/ . Thanks for the help, btw.

Comment: Yes. Those wheels are pretty cheap as is, so I'm not sure why you were expecting something cheaper. And its not necessarily clear that they're a significant upgrade. Try working with your bike shop or something, because a lot of cheaper wheels need some adjustment even when they're new (and based on this question, it's highly unlikely that you're equipped to check the wheel's adjustment out of the box).

Comment: You can definitely run 28mm tires no problem in the CAAD 10 disc frame. I have 28mm conti's and there's probably room to go up to 31mm, fyi.